# Calculate probability of previous occurrences in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a data of the format:

(Table A)

| Site | Day | Event Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Site A | Mon | Event 1 |
| Site A | Mon | Event 2 |
| Site A | Tue | Event 1 |
| Site A | Tue | Event 3 |
| Site A | Wed | Event 3 |
| Site A | Wed | Event 1 |
| Site B | Wed | Event 1 |

I now want to create a "full" table equivalent of the above (i.e. all permutation of the site, day and event type present in the new table) with calculated probabilities of an event happening from Mon - Wed (i.e. In Site A, Event 1 has a probability of 1.00 because it existed for each day while Event 2 only has a probability of 0.33 because it only happened on a Mon. Similarly, for Site B only Event 1 has a probability of 0.33 while events 2 and 3 have probabilities of 0).

(Table B)

| Site | Day | Event Type | P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Site A | Mon | Event 1 | 1.00 |
| Site A | Mon | Event 2 | 0.33 |
| Site A | Mon | Event 3 | 0.66 |
| Site A | Tue | Event 1 | 1.00 |
| Site A | Tue | Event 2 | 0.33 |
| Site A | Tue | Event 3 | 0.66 |
| Site A | Wed | Event 1 | 1.00 |
| Site A | Wed | Event 2 | 0.33 |
| Site A | Wed | Event 3 | 0.66 |
| Site B | Mon | Event 1 | 0.33 |
| Site B | Mon | Event 2 | 0.00 |
| Site B | Mon | Event 3 | 0.00 |
| Site B | Tue | Event 1 | 0.33 |
| Site B | Tue | Event 2 | 0.00 |
| Site B | Tue | Event 3 | 0.00 |
| Site B | Wed | Event 1 | 0.33 |
| Site B | Wed | Event 2 | 0.00 |
| Site B | Wed | Event 3 | 0.00 |

How can I do this efficiently in Big Query? I have not been able to successfully implement it so far. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select Site, Day, EventType, 
  round(countif(format('%t', t) != '(NULL, NULL, NULL)') over win / count(*) over win, 2) p
from (select distinct Site from your_table),
  (select distinct Day from your_table),
  (select distinct EventType from your_table)
left join your_table t
using (Site, Day, EventType)
window win as (partition by Site, EventType)
# order by Site, Day, EventType
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]